# How to select all previous siblings of element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, siblings

Let's say I have a div with next content:

```
<div id="divOne">
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <div id="aggregatedDiv"></div>
    <p> three </p>
</div>
```

So is there any way to remove first three elements? I don't know the number of elements. I just want to remove everything before `id="aggregatedDiv"` including it.

I have to append the result as html to some other div.

```
$("#otherDiv").append(resultOfSlicedDivOneHtml);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) to selecting all previous sibling of element and use [`.addBack()`](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/) to adding previous selector (`#aggregatedDiv`) to current set of selected element.

```js
$("#aggregatedDiv").prevAll().addBack().css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divOne">
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <div id="aggregatedDiv">#</div>
    <p> three </p>
</div>
```

If you want to add selected element to another element, use bottom example:

```js
$("#aggregatedDiv").prevAll().addBack().appendTo("#divTwo");
```

```css
#divTwo {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divOne">
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <div id="aggregatedDiv">#</div>
    <p> three </p>
</div>
<div id="divTwo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above you can use `.prevAll()`, but also you will need `.addBack()` to achieve what you want:

```
$("#otherDiv").append($("#aggregatedDiv").prevAll().addBack());
```

Comment: andSelf was deprecated in jQuery 1.8. addBack should be used instead. Also, a minor point, this answer just removes the elements from divOne, but doesn't add the to otherDiv.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for tip. Not used this function before. Also fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var elements = $("#aggregatedDiv").prevAll(); //gets everything before aggregatedDiv
elements = elements.add($("#aggregatedDiv")); //we want aggregatedDiv in the collection as well
$("#otherDiv").append(elements); //move them all into the other div
```